# rabbitmq, Java client works via SSL, but .NET one does not

Tags: java, c#, .net, ssl, rabbitmq

I’m new to rabbitmq but I have to connect to remote broker to send and receive messages. Remote server is out of my control and it’s almost impossible to get answers from its team. Nevertheless, I have address, port, virtual host and user credentials at my disposal. Server uses TLS v1.2.
The problem is I cannot establish connection to the server with .NET client. Client is “rabbitmq.client.5.1.0”, .NET Framework 4.5.1 and VS 2017. My code is:

```
public bool Start() {
  try {
    var f = new ConnectionFactory();
    f.UserName = "TestUser";
    f.Password = "TestPwd";
    f.HostName = "x.x.x.x";
    f.Port = 5673;
    f.VirtualHost = "TestVH";

    f.Ssl.Version = SslProtocols.Tls12;
    f.Ssl.Enabled = true;
    f.Ssl.AcceptablePolicyErrors = SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors
        | SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch
        | SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable;
    var c = f.CreateConnection();
  } catch( Exception e ) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

It throws an exception which innermost is:

> Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

([Wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ0Do.png)).

If I do it with Java (`1.8, amqp-client-4.0.2`), I can successfully connect to the server.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception{
  ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
  factory.setHost("x.x.x.x");
  factory.setPort(5673);
  factory.setUsername( "TestUser" );
  factory.setPassword( "TestPwd" );
  factory.setVirtualHost( "TestVH" );

  factory.useSslProtocol("TLSv1.2");
  Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
}
```

[Wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mivAA.png)

I would like to use C# to get the job done but I can not sort this thing out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What if you try to use Tls11 or Tls10 ?

Comment: It brings me the same result - remote server closes connection =\

Comment: If you can get the logged message from RabbitMQ, that may help. Otherwise, I suggest following the [TLS troubleshooting guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html). What I would like to know is what cipher is being used by the Java connection vs the .NET one. That may be the difference. Use the `openssl s_client` command to get that information.

Comment: Thx for the tip, I will look into it!

Answer (score 2):

try changing this line:

```
f.Ssl.Version = SslProtocols.Tls12;
```

to this:

```
f.Ssl.Version = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Ssl2;
```

If that works then you narrow them down

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it gives the same result. I was curious about Java, seems it uses some other settings (for ssl?). Its message longer then one C# is sending.